# How do I set up a service?

Tags: 11.04, server, services, upstart, init.d

I have a script that I would like to run as a service on my Ubuntu Server 11.04 headless box. That is, I want to have the correct files under */etc/init.d/* and to be able to control it via the `service` command.

Is there any guide available that will show me how to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unless you are using 15.04 or any later release (which uses `systemd`), you will probably be better off if you turn your script into an Upstart job, rather than follow the examples you'll find in `/etc/init.d/` (which are System V-style init scripts, which Ubuntu and other distributions are moving away from).

The [Upstart Cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) has an enormous amount of information about how Upstart jobs work.  Although I wouldn't describe it as a HOWTO, if you combine the information there with looking through the stock Ubuntu Upstart jobs in `/etc/init/` you will start to get the picture.

I suggest starting with section 4 and 5 of the Cookbook, ["Concepts and Terminology"](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#concepts-and-terminology) and ["Configuration"](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#configuration)

Answer (score 12):

Here is a very simple example how to create an upstart script:
https://wiki.frugalware.org/index.php/Upstart_Job_HOWTO

UPDATE: above link is broken. Here is an example of a script:

```
description "My startup service"
author "You or someone else"
version "3.14"

pre-start script
    echo 'Starting my service ...'
end script

start on net-device-up
stop on runlevel [!2345]

console output

respawn

exec /path/to/your/custom/script
```

Adapt as necessary.

You should place the script in `/etc/init/yourfilename.conf`

Then reload the configuration with:

```
sudo initctl reload-configuration
```

And if all is OK, you should be able to start it with:

```
sudo start yourfilename
```

Comment: https://wiki.frugalware.org/index.php/Upstart_Job_HOWTO . Link is broken.