# Deluge start-up script works but won't start daemon on startup

Tags: 14.04, startup, init.d, deluge

I've gone through the instructions [here](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/ThinClient) to configure Deluge, and I've also gone through [these](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/Service/DebianUbuntuInitd) instructions to set up the necessary scripts.

The username I chose for `DELUGED_USER` was the user name I was logged in with, i.e. the Unity desktop user.

I executed each of the commands as instructed and received no error messages. Upon restart, deluged was not running. When I executed `sudo update-rc.d deluge-daemon defaults` I got a warning that the entry already exists. Manually executing `sudo invoke-rc.d deluge-daemon start` works, and I am able to connect.

It appears as though the start-up script will not execute at start-up, however there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the script as executing it manually successfully starts the daemon.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score -1):

On 14.04 don't use `inid.d` use `Upstart` scripts instead. There is a full [Upstart guide](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/Service/Upstart) on the Deluge site walking you through setting them up.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something but I don't see where on that page it says it will start automatically at startup and stay running. I just followed those instructions and restarted the machine and deluged wasn't running. I had to run `sudo start deluged` to start it.

Comment: Starting an upstart service will automatically start it at boot.

Comment: Well, it doesn't. After 3 reboots it still doesn't start. I must type `sudo start deluged` every time I boot. I followed the instructions on the linked page.

Comment: Have a look at this question on debugging upstart: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62812/why-isnt-my-upstart-service-starting-on-system-boot

Comment: I followed Upstart guide, following everything to the letter. But when I start `sudo start deluged` a process starts but as soon as I try to `sudo stop deluged` I get `stop: Unknown instance:`. It works fine for `deluge-web` i.e. process starts/stops normally but of course `web` is useless w/o daemon. Only changes: adding user:pwd to `auth` and changing defaults port in `core.conf` and `web.conf`. `daemon.log` is empty, `web.log` has No such file or directory: '/var/lib/deluge/.config/deluge/hostlist.conf.1.2` and `Connection was refused by other side`.

Comment: @Ozzah At least your service starts manually. Mine just doesn't. Did you make any changes to the script i.e. password change via `auth` file and port change via `core.conf` file and `web.conf` file.